# WordPress Multisite uploads broken images

Tags: wordpress, upload, media, multisite

I am having an issue with one of my sub-sites media library. All it uploads are broken images. It loads fine locally but for some reason it gives me the error

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://mjstokes.com/victoria/files/2017/02/model6-150x150.jpg"

Locally all uploads goes into my `wp-content/uploads` path, but as hosted live they go into my files folder, which is in `domain/theme/files`. I have already contact my hosting company and they were unable to assist me.

**Note: The images are present and the file permissions are set to 750 with owner/group 776 774.**

Comment: What is a "files folder" and why is it different on live?

Comment: Because for the live multisite their default path is "domain/theme/files". Also there was no need for you to edit out the last paragraph. I'm in an urgent need to have this resolved immediately.

Comment: Useful reading: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495). Personally I think it is obvious that "urgent" demands should not be made of volunteers, but the community has discussed it anyway, since we get a lot of queue-jumpers.

Comment: All I'm asking for is a possible solution. If you have one please share it.

Comment: Try logging onto your remote server (via SSH or FTP) and see if your expected files are in there. Also, how does the URL path `/victoria/files/2017/02/model6-150x150.jpg` map to the file system path `domain/theme/files`? Do you mean that `domain` is your public folder i.e. the root of your WordPress project? If so then perhaps `model6-150x150.jpg` is missing or the permissions are incorrect.

Comment: If it is present then please edit your question to include the file permissions, the owner user and the owner group. You can get these from FTP or `ls -l` from SSH.

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at my files and check the permissions via FTP. I see you've been all over the site editing and commenting all my questions I ever posted since I joined. Do you work for the company?

Comment: Useful reading: [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).